# How to access fetched data from ReferenceInput to fill ReferenceArrayInput choices in react admin?

Tags: react-admin

when I fetch data

```
<ReferenceInput
source="estateId"
reference="estates"
>
<SelectInput optionText="name" />
</ReferenceInput>
```

i get an answer for every estate like that:

```
{
"id": 5,
"name": "test",
"livingUnits": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "all"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "1."
}
]
}
```

how can I access the livingunits information to fill  ReferenceArrayInput choices?

```
<ReferenceArrayInput
source="livingUnitIds"            
>
<SelectArrayInput>
<ChipField source="name" />
</SelectArrayInput>              
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, I've searched a lot on source code and didn't found a clean solution for that. `<ReferenceArrayInput>` needs an array with the ids of the related resource, it then queries the dataProvider for the resource and the ids on the array. A solution I applied was change the answer of the request to give a property that was an array with the id of the related resource, in your example the answer for the estate should be something like:

`{
"id": 5,
"name": "test",
"livingUnitsIds": [1, 2]
}`

I did this because I had control over backend, if that's not your case, probably you'll need to implement a custom `<ReferenceInput>` or a component that fetches the data you want on component `onComponentDidMount` lifecycle method.